# Error in running the selenium script

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, maven-2

I have an automated selenium script Inside a maven project which is to be used for performing certain functionalities. The problem is when i trigger it with eclipse using Testng ,
it fails and eclipse throws me some error which am not able to reslove.
I have attched the error trace along with it.`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[text()='com.prism.soap.sftp.msg.mping.iflow']/../../../..//div[@class='OneByOne sapMGTHdrContent'] (tried for 25 second(s) with 2 SECONDS interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at com.webui.Others.webui.tooling.Prism_Master_Class.webdriver_wait(Prism_Master_Class.java:47)
    at com.webui.Monitor.automation.Prism_Selenium_Monitor_Tab.prism_monitor_messageProcessing(Prism_Selenium_Monitor_Tab.java:732)
    at com.webui.Others.webui.tooling.Message_Processing_Vaidation.messageProcessingCheck(Message_Processing_Vaidation.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //*[text()='com.prism.soap.sftp.msg.mping.iflow']/../../../..//div[@class='OneByOne sapMGTHdrContent']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INLN50942827A', ip: '10.53.219.90', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:883)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
    ... 27 more`

Comment: you error reads `NoSuchElementException` which is possible when the findElement fails to find the actual WebElement you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems coming due to element is not found using your locator code, it is called **NoSuchElementException**. Check your code again.